# Can't change IE being the default HTTP handler on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I've just installed a fresh Win8 x64 and CoolNovo browser (which is a modified chrome).
Every time I set the default HTTP/HTTPS handlers to CoolNovo and press save, next time I open the screen IE is still the default.

[image: Program Associations]
When I try to make CoolNovo the default browser from withing its settings, I get this screen:

[image: How do you want to open this type of link (http)?]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an anti-malware/system protection software running (that may be restoring the setting)?

Comment: Just AVG free. With firefox this worked, so I guess that's a problem with CoolNovo.